# How can i add a north arrow in QgsComposition?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, print-composer

I'm trying to add an svg image of north arrow in QgsComposition using this code:

```
mapRenderer = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()
theComposition = QgsComposition(mapRenderer)
theComposition.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)
northarrowIcon = QgsComposerPicture(theComposition)
northarrowIcon.setPos(QPointF(50,110))
northarrowIcon.setPictureFile("./svg/north_arrows/north-arrow_3_simple_symmetric_triangular.svg")
theComposition.addItem(northarrowIcon)
```

i don't have an execution problem but the arrow is not shown.

Can someone check and give me an idea what can be the cause of that.

Comment: Did you try to use `theComposition.addComposerPicture( northarrowIcon )` instead of `addItem()`

Comment: yes i tried it, but no result.

Comment: Did you try to specify the full pathname instead of relative?

Comment: yes i tried that,but i still don't see the arrow

Comment: @fkilimohamed did you ever find your solution? i'm looking to do the same sort of thing, except with a png

Comment: No i just gave up.

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't know if you find a solution, did you try setPicturePath? I would like to know if you find a way? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found a solution for QGIS version 2.10.1. The size of the box/scene containing the image need to be big enough, otherwise it is not visible. According to the [pyQgis API documentation](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsComposerPicture.html#af2b1e17d32bc85448b4c4cef315bf2d5) it also resizes the svg. You have to add the following line before adding it to the composition.

```
northarrowIcon.setSceneRect(QrectF(0,0,20,20))
```

Maybe it was not necessary to set in some older versions of QGIS.

Off course play around with the dimensions, `QrectF(0,0,20,20)` was perfect for the resolution / arrow I am using.