# addItem() method doesn't work

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I show you my code, but basically, I have been following the steps in the official bibliography about [Map Composition](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html#output-using-map-composer) The code works, but I don't get the items I have been adding to the map (scalebar, labels, and legend). Sorry, some words are in Spanish

QGIS 2.14 (Essen)

I'm using Text Editor of QGIS

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *

lyr = QgsVectorLayer("\\ROUTE\\MUNICIPIOS.shp", "Municipios", "ogr")
reg = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
reg.addMapLayer(lyr)
##etiquetamos
#etiquetas = QgsPalLayerSettings()
#etiquetas.readFromLayer(municipios)
#etiquetas.enabled = True
#etiquetas.fieldName = 'Municipios'
#etiquetas.placement= QgsPalLayerSettings.Horizontal
#etiquetas.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Size,True,True,'8','')
#etiquetas.writeToLayer(municipios)
##fin de etiquetas

#EMPEZAMOS CON LA IMAGEN

i = QImage(QSize(800,800), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
c = QColor('#cda56d')
i.fill(c.rgb())
p = QPainter()
p.begin(i)

lyrs = reg.mapLayers().keys()
#AQUI EL MAP RENDERER 
el_renderer = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()
#el_renderer = QgsMapRenderer()
el_renderer.setLayerSet(lyrs)
rect = QgsRectangle(el_renderer.fullExtent())
rect.scale(1.2)
el_renderer.setExtent(rect)
el_renderer.setOutputSize(i.size(), i.logicalDpiX())
el_renderer.render(p)
p.end()

# Aqui tengo mi COMPOSICION DE MAPA ----> . QgsComposition
composition = QgsComposition(el_renderer) 

composition.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)
#composition.setPaperSize(215.9, 279.4)
# Mi QgsComposerMap
w, h = composition.paperWidth() * .50, composition.paperHeight() * .50
x = (composition.paperWidth() - w) / 2
y = ((composition.paperHeight() - h)) / 2
componer_mapa = QgsComposerMap(composition,x,y,w,h)
composition.addItem(componer_mapa)

#Aqui termina el ComposerMap

#Aqui esta mi etiquetado. QgsComposerLabel
etiqueta = QgsComposerLabel(composition)
#QgsComposerLabel::adjustSizeToText
etiqueta.adjustSizeToText()
#QgsComposerLabel::setText
etiqueta.setText('Municipios')
#QgsComposerLabel::marginX()
etiqueta.marginX()
#QgsComposerLabel::marginY()
etiqueta.marginY()
#QgsComposerLabel::displayText()
#etiqueta.displayText()
#QgsComposerLabel::displayName()
#etiqueta.displayName()
composition.addItem(etiqueta) #DOESN'T WORK

legend = QgsComposerLegend(composition)
legend.model().setLayerSet(el_renderer.layerSet())
composition.addItem(legend)

scBar = QgsComposerScaleBar(composition)
scBar.setStyle('Numeric') 
scBar.setComposerMap(componer_mapa)
scBar.applyDefaultSize()
composition.addItem(scBar) #DOESN'T WORK

i.save("RUTA\\mapa_con_todo.jpg","jpg")
```

Comment: [This post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86451/how-can-i-add-a-north-arrow-in-qgscomposition) implies that there might be a problem with the size of the item you're trying to add. Have you tried to call `adjustSizeToText()` *after* `setText()`?

Comment: It is not working, but should I use a new method to adjust all the items?

Comment: Do I have to use iface.mapCanvas().refresh() method ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really familiar with map composition in PyQgis. I was just sharing a post showing a similar issue. Hope you will find a solution to your problem, though.

Comment: well, I already have the solution, but the great problem now is that I can't see my shapefile features jeje